# is it possible to automatically refresh component when getx value changed flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

I am using [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) `get: ^4.3.8` as the state management component in flutter, when I using this code to update the controller value:

```
var expand = controller.newTaskExpanded.value;
controller.newTaskExpanded(!expand);
```

I found the component did not refresh, then I have to invoke the getx refresh function like this:

```
controller.refresh();
```

this is the controller properties define:

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  List<Widget> widgetsList = List.empty(growable: true);
  List<Todo> tasks = List.empty(growable: true);
  var newTaskExpanded = true.obs;
  var completedTaskExpanded = false.obs;
}
```

is is possible to auto refresh the flutter component when controller properties value changed? should I invoke the refresh function every time change the value of getx controller?

Comment: have you tried adding Obx on the widget or getbuilder then using update(). ?

Answer (score 3):

Reactive programming with Get is as easy as using setState.

Let's imagine that you have a name variable and want that every time you change it, all widgets that use it are automatically changed.

This is your count variable:

```
var name = 'Jonatas Borges';
```

To make it observable, you just need to add ".obs" to the end of it:

```
var name = 'Jonatas Borges'.obs;
```

And in the UI, when you want to show that value and update the screen whenever the values changes, simply do this:

```
Obx(() => Text("${controller.name}"));
```

For more , refer: https://pub.dev/packages/get/example

Answer (score 2):

wrap you UI with Obx builder like

`appBar: AppBar(title: Obx(() => Text("Clicks: ${c.count}"))),`

it will auto refresh the UI on value change
if you want to refresh the UI manually then use GetBuilder and when you need to update the UI just call controller.update();

Answer (score 2):

As @Muhammad Sherad explained, your widget code should be wrapped with `Obx()` so that you widget can look for variable change and re-render the widget.